# Django Rest Framework test not working with DRF APIClient() instance

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, swagger

I am trying to run this Django test of my DRF API endpoint:

```py
def test_list_settlements(self):
        
        url = reverse('settlements:settlement_api-list', kwargs={'team_slug':'team-slug'})

        try:
            team = Team.objects.get(slug=self.venue.team.slug)
        # Check if the team from the URL is one of the user's teams
        except Team.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("No team matches the given slug for this user.")
        pdb.set_trace()
        url = reverse('settlements:settlement_api-list', kwargs={'team_slug': 'team-slug'})
        
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data), 1)
        self.assertEqual(response.data[0]['id'], self.settlement.id)
```

I set the pdb.set_trace() to see if I could discover anything fishy, and I'm super stumped.

With the client, I verified it's properly logged in, and can make calls to any other endpoint successfully returning values. In swagger, if I use this particular end point, of which the `reverse()` computes to

```py
/a/team-slug/settlements/api/
```

it will return all the settlements correctly in the swagger UI.

But when I make the call here with self.client.get(url), it returns a 404. When the `pdb.set_trace()` starts, I can call the client, and other endpoint calls successfully, but this particular one gives me a 404.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it works in every other situation (being Swagger UI  and my dev environment calling from localhost:8000), except my test `APIClient()` instance, which can successfully call other endpoints in the same instance. I haven't been able to find any relevant articles to this problem either, so my googling/searching has been fairly fruitless.

Here's the view for it in my api_views.py file:

```py
from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema,extend_schema_view
from ..models import Settlement
from ..serializers import SettlementSerializer

@extend_schema(tags=["settlements"])
@extend_schema_view(
    create=extend_schema(operation_id="settlements_api_create"),
    list=extend_schema(operation_id="settlements_api_list"),
    retrieve=extend_schema(operation_id="settlements_api_retrieve"),
    update=extend_schema(operation_id="settlements_api_update"),
    partial_update=extend_schema(operation_id="settlements_api_partial_update"),
    destroy=extend_schema(operation_id="settlements_api_destroy"),
)
class SettlementViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """API endpoint that allows settlements to be viewed or edited."""

    queryset = Settlement.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SettlementSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrHasUserAPIKey]
    
    def get_queryset(self):        
        # filter queryset based on the team slug from the URL, and the current user
        team_slug = self.kwargs['team_slug']   
        print('SettlementViewSet Hit')     
        try:
            team = Team.objects.get(slug=team_slug, members=self.request.user)
        # Check if the team from the URL is one of the user's teams
        except Team.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("No team matches the given slug for this user.")
        
        return Settlement.objects.filter(venue__team=team).order_by("id")
```

And this is my urls.py setup:

```py
urlpatterns = ...<other urls>

# DRF config for API views (required for React Teams, implementation, optional otherwise)
router.register("api", views.SettlementViewSet, basename="settlement_api")
urlpatterns += router.urls
```